# How to transform SOAP to JSON array in wso2 ESB using script mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm trying to transform the soap request coming from our clients to the REST service we have using wso2 script mediator.

Input (SOAP):

```
<tran:Request xmlns:tran="http://schemas.demo.com/tran.xsd" xmlns:sub="http://schemas.demo.com/admin.xsd" ...>
    <tran:Specific>
        <tran:Subject>
            <sub:Transaction>
                <sub:postingIndicator>false</sub:postingIndicator>
                <sub:referenceId>23645723</sub:referenceId>
                <sub:entries>
                    <sub:entry>
                        <sub:accountNumber>AC0123456</sub:accountNumber>
                        <sub:credit>true</sub:credit>
                        <sub:amount>
                            <sub:amountValue>20</sub:amountValue>
                            <sub:currencySymbol>USD</sub:currencySymbol>                                
                        </sub:amount>
                    </sub:entry>
                    <sub:entry>
                        <sub:accountId>AC987654</sub:accountId>
                        <sub:credit>false</sub:credit>
                        <sub:amount>
                            <sub:amountValue>20</sub:amountValue>
                            <sub:currencySymbol>USD</sub:currencySymbol>                                
                        </sub:amount>
                    </sub:entry>
                    <sub:entry> .....
                </sub:entries>
            </sub:Transaction>
        </tran:Subject>
    </tran:Specific>
</tran:Request>
```

Expected output (JSON):

```
{
    "indicator": false,
    "reference": 23645723,
    "postingEntries": [
        {
            "accountId": "AC0123456",
            "credit": "true",
            "amount": {
                "value": "20",
                "currency": "USD"
            }               
        },
        {
            "accountId": "AC987654",
            "credit": "false",
            "amount": {
                "value": "20",
                "currency": "USD"
            }               
        },
        .....
    ]
}
```

So far I was able to map the "non-array" xml elements into JSON but stuck at iterating `entries` "xml array". This is the script mediator I have now.

```
<sequence name="soap-to-rest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <script language="js">
        <![CDATA[
            var log = mc.getServiceLog();
            var payload = mc.getPayloadXML();
            log.info(payload);

            var adminns = new Namespace('http://schemas.demo.com/admin.xsd');

            // How to iterate the <sub:entries> and fill this array up? <===========
            var postingEntries[];

            mc.setPayloadJSON(
                {
                    "indicator": mc.getPayloadXML()..adminns::postingIndicator.toString(),
                    "reference": mc.getPayloadXML()..adminns::referenceId.toString(),
                    "postingEntries": postingEntries
                }
            );
        ]]>
    </script>
</sequence>
```

How do I populate the `postingEntries` json array before setting it in `mc.setPayloadJSON()`?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use the data mapper mediator for your use case. Using the integration studio you can easily map the inputs and the outputs. Refer to the document [1] for this.

[1]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/data-Mapper-Mediator/